# Manually creating main.xml error

Tags: android, xml

For my project I have to have two `.java` classes and two .xml files. The first one that I have created is `SplashActivity.java`. After I have created that class, put some code in there, and worked with my `activity_splash.xml`. I needed to create the `MainActivity.java` class. I went into the

> AndroidManifest.xml -> Application -> Add -> Actiivity. Name ->
>   .MainActivity

In my `MainActivity.java` class I write an `onCreate()` method to create the `activity_main.xml`. However, my eclipse emulator underlines the activity_main with a red underline. When I move my mouse to it, it gives me several options **"Create filed "activity_main" in type layout", "Create constant "activity_main" in type layout"**. I am not sure which ones of those are correct way to fix the issue that's why I decided not to mess with `R.java`. But I am confused why I have that error because as far as I am concerned my code is correct.

The following are the codes:

**SplashActivity.java**

```
package com.example.easternmusic;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            startActivity(new 
Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        }

    };
    Timer opening = new Timer ();
    opening.schedule(task, 5000); 

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new   PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.easternmusic"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.easternmusic.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.easternmusic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}

}
```

Comment: There might be some problem with your activity_main.xml file.Post your xml file.

Comment: Make sure that you created the layout file `activity_main.xml` into `res/layout/` folder. Also, you can try to clean and rebuild the project. Then, as AHegde said, you should edit your question and post the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each activity consist of a layout(xml file) and a java class. Here you create the class MainActivity but you forget to add layout of the activity i.e xml file.when you write this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`. its mean you are setting layout here.`Activity_main` is the name of the layout file.which you dont add in your layout folder. So the answer to this question is go to your layout folder and add xml file with name `activity_main`. Your problem will be solved.